# animation rotates over long angle (interpolation)

Tags: animation, keyframes, interpolation

i am struggling with keyframing my 2d rig in blender:

sometimes, the Rotation is interpolated over the Long angle: even though a bone only rotates About 40° between keyframes, the Interpolation goes over the Long angle (rotates over 300°).

what can cause This behaviour and how can i fix this Problem? i assume it is a Problem with my rig?

Things i tried:

- adding even more keys inbetween barely fixes the issues
- i already did Play around with the Roll value of the bone, without any success.
- the parent bones are not animated in this instance.
- linear Interpolation does not solve it either

using blender 2.79

stripped down blend file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ascsde05SosCnsJV6LpiRZEn2T9HaQ

keyframe 1
[image: keyframe 1]
keyframe 2
[image: keyframe 2]
inbetween
[image: inbetween frame]
curves dont look funky either
[image: Animation curves]

Comment: if you're talking about armR, I've deleted the second keyframe, then rotated it counter clockwise and it works, what you say is weird because by default it looks like it uses the shortest path, so if you make a 40° rotation it will do the 40°, not the 320°

Comment: indeed, deleting it and making a new key solved the problem.  seems like keyframes with -1 in W rotate the long way. i have no idea when / how i created those though.  i ended up redoing several animations, so if anyone knows a fix, im interested